# Primefaces Button in Header

Tags: user-interface, primefaces, uibutton, styles

Is it possible to place a button inside of a header of a panel?

What I've read the following should work, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

```
<p:panel id="panel">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:commandButton value="Click"/>
    </f:facet>
<p:panel>
```

Thanks to all who can help

Comment: What do you mean? Button doesn't show up?

Answer (score 2):

Replace `header` to **`actions`**

```
<p:panel>
    <f:facet name="actions">
        <p:commandButton value="Click"/>
    </f:facet>
<p:panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <h:form>
                        <p:panel id="panel">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <p:commandButton value="Click"/>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:panel>
                    </h:form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, in header or footer...

```
   <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton  value="Update Total" update="tabla_gral" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" id="ajax2" actionListener="#{consumoMaterial.actualizarSaldos}"/>
   </f:facet>
```